# Strange ng-repeat behaviour with local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I am just playing around with ionic and local storage. I am messing with the ionic example app to customise it a bit and I am running into a snag. Basically the home page lists items. Once the user goes into the item they can add to a task list.

To create an item on the home page the user opens a modal and enters info (title,date, etc...) and then stores the items in local storage. The item array has a nested array for the task list.

once the user goes into an item they can open a modal that adds a task. Once submitted the task is pushed to the nested array which works great and outputs:

However, when the user goes back to the home page where all items are listed there are just a number of empty objects repeated (looking in local storage the object is perfect).

My list controller and inner list controller:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($filter, $scope, $stateParams, $timeout, $ionicModal, Eventers) {


    var createEventer = function(eventerId, eventerTitle, eventerVenue, eventerDay, eventerMonth, eventerYear, eventerDate) {
        var newEventer = Eventers.newEventer(eventerId,eventerTitle, eventerVenue, eventerDay, eventerMonth, eventerYear, eventerDate);
        $scope.eventers.push(newEventer);
        Eventers.save($scope.eventers);
        }
        $scope.eventers = Eventers.all();

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('new-event.html', function(modal) {
        $scope.eventerModal = modal;
    }, 
    {
        focusFirstInput: false,
        scope: $scope
    });

    ////////////////////////////////

    $scope.date = new Date();
    console.log($scope.date);

    ////////////////////////////////

    $scope.createEventer = function(eventer, index) {
        var eventerId = localStorage.clickcount;
        var eventerTitle = eventer.title;
        var eventerVenue = eventer.venue;
        var eventerDay = eventer.day;
        var eventerMonth = eventer.month;
        var eventerYear = eventer.year;
        var eventerDate =  $scope.date;
       if (eventerId,eventerTitle, eventerVenue, eventerDay, eventerMonth, eventerYear, eventerDate) {
            createEventer(eventerId,eventerTitle, eventerVenue, eventerDay, eventerMonth, eventerYear, eventerDate);
            $scope.eventerModal.hide();
            eventer.title = "";
            eventer.venue = "";
            eventer.day = "";
            eventer.month = "";
            eventer.year = "";

        }


        console.log(eventer);
    };


})
```

and my inner controller:

```
.controller('ProfileInnerCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams,$ionicModal, $timeout, Eventers) {
 $scope.eventer = Eventers.get($stateParams.eventerId);

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('new-task.html', function(modal) {
        $scope.eventerModal = modal;
    }, 
    {
        focusFirstInput: false,
        scope: $scope
    });

 $scope.createTask = function(task) {

        $scope.eventer.tasks.push({
            title: task.title
        });

        console.log(task.title);
        Eventers.save($scope.eventer);
        task.title = "";
        $scope.eventerModal.hide();

    };

    $scope.newTask = function() {
        $scope.eventerModal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeNewTask = function() {
        $scope.eventerModal.hide();
    }
     $scope.completionChanged = function() {
        Eventers.save($scope.eventers);
    };
})
```

--------EDIT: Add Factory-------

```
.factory('Eventers', function() {

            /**/


    return {
        all: function() {
          var eventerString = window.localStorage['eventers'];
          if (eventerString) {
            return angular.fromJson(eventerString);
          }
          return [];
        },
        save: function(eventers) {
          window.localStorage['eventers'] = angular.toJson(eventers);
        },
        newEventer: function(eventerId, eventerTitle,eventerVenue , eventerDay, eventerMonth, eventerYear, eventerDate) {
            return {
                id: eventerId,
                title: eventerTitle,
                venue: eventerVenue,
                day: eventerDay,
                month: eventerMonth,
                year: eventerYear,
                date: eventerDate,
                tasks: []
            };
        },
        get: function(eventerId){
          var hell = window.localStorage['eventers'];
          var eventers = JSON.parse(hell);

            for (var i = 0; i < eventers.length; i++) {


              if (parseInt(eventers[i].id) === parseInt(eventerId)){
                    console.log(eventerId);
                    return eventers[i];
                }
            }

            return null;
        }


    }

});
```

Added images: the first 2 show the home page and local storage before added a task. the last 2 show local storage after adding task and the home page

[image: How it looks before adding task. Home page]

[image: JSON before added task]

[image: JSON after adding task]

[image: Home page after adding task]

Comment: You have posted a lot of code, it would be easier if you just included the essential code.

Comment: @simeg I toned it down a bit to just my controllers

Comment: Are you sure your 'get' function is good?

Comment: Can you show your save and get functions

Comment: @FranePoljak added my factory

Comment: Well, when you create a new task you save $scope.eventer in the localStorage, which only has titles in it.

Comment: @FranePoljak it pushes it to tasks and then saves eventer to local storage. Once a task has been created local storage is perfectly formated with the new task in the tasks array. the problem is that when I go back to the page that is repeating the lists it just shows empty objects repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you create a new task you save $scope.eventer in the localStorage, which only has titles in it.

Why not push the whole task object in the $scope.eventer?

```
$scope.createTask = function(task) {

    $scope.eventer.tasks.push(task);
...
```

EDIT:

Your eventers in localStorage after adding task are not an array, so the ng-repeat takes each key in the object.

try Eventers.save([$scope.eventer]); for test, but you'lll have to rethink the whole proccess, what when you have more than one object in the array? you will lose the old ones this way

Comment: it pushes it to tasks and then saves eventer to local storage. Once a task has been created local storage is perfectly formated with the new task in the tasks array. the problem is that when I go back to the page that is repeating the lists it just shows empty objects repeated

Comment: Well I misunderstood that, but this part is definitley suspicious to me. I don't think you should do "Eventers.save($scope.eventer);" at all in createTask function. Also, try $timeout(function(){$scope.$apply();}); after $scope.eventers.push(newEventer); in createEventer.

Comment: When you add a new task in existing eventer, you should update it in main array ($scope.eventers) before saving eventers, and what you do is pass only that eventer in the save function, and then save the main array without it being modified

Comment: The thing is that after using: "Eventers.save($scope.eventer);" my local storage looks like this: {"id":"1","title":"test","venue":"there","day":"01","month":"January","year":"2016","date":"2016-02-23T11:55:23.352Z","tasks":[{"title":"Task 1"}]} which is exactly how I want it. I will try using $scope.$apply

Comment: I added images. the first 2 show the home page and local storage before added a task. the last 2 show local storage after adding task and the home page

Comment: Your eventers in localStorage after adding task are not an array, so the ng-repeat takes each key in the object.

Comment: try Eventers.save([$scope.eventer]); for test, but you'lll have to rethink the whole proccess, what when you have more than one object in the array? you will lose the old ones this way

Comment: Ah good point. I will have to go change this somewhat. Going to mark as the answer for the help. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, thanks for accepting. I will edit the answer so it contains the solution